# Occasional pow error starting application (Response was not received)

Tags: rack-pow

I'm getting this error in pow, maybe one in 30 or 50 requests:

Error starting application

Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.

```
Error: Response was not received
  at Client._finishRequest (/Users/duarte/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:77:27)
  at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/duarte/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:38:21)
  at Client.emit (events.js:88:20)
  at Array.0 (net.js:335:10)
  at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

I am using:

- rails (3.2.11)
- ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
- rbenv
- Anvil (mac app for managing pow symlinks)

I don't have any custom version of ruby set. I've had this for about a month now. When I get the error I reload a few times and it usually goes away by itself within a minute. Sometimes I just start WEBrick and that works. I tried installing node through homebrew and also npm. I've reinstalled pow a few times, but no luck!

It seems like it's a problem with node or something that has a bad install, but I can't figure out what it might be! This is a new laptop and I've been getting the error from the beginning, ever since I first set everything up.

Comment: Just a note - it doesn't help with your problem at all, but it's important - you should update to Rails 3.2.12 due to some new security fixes: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/11/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-12-3-1-11-and-2-3-17-have-been-released/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same problem: this was solved by re-installing gcc and rebuilding ruby.